# why compiler make two identical code for same template type

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, types, compiler-optimization

For a template defined as:

```
struct sameT{};
template <class T>
void print(){/*do stuff*/}

int main(){
    print<sameT>();
    print<sameT>();
}
```

When I watched the machine code generated by gcc for above code, there was exactly same 2 function with same content for print. I had expected this only when i had done

```
print<type1>();
print<type2>();
```

Wouldn't the compiler supposed to generate a single bunch of assembly per type. I mean to use the same function twice for both `print<int>()`. What am I missing?

Comment: The linker should remove the duplicates. The compiler just instantiates the template wherever it is used. The linker cleans up the mess.

Comment: Could also be inlining optimizations.

Comment: I [can't reproduce](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/kFAofA) this, even at O0 with no linking.

Comment: @JesperJuhl how can i see that?

Comment: @Dev-il Easy; compile and link the final executable (or library), then disassemble it and see that there's a single instance of the function left. Look up tools like `objdump`, `readelf` and `nm`. Also check out `c++filt` to help with demangling.